# Array to string conversion error in /Twig/Environment.php when using Timber

Tags: twig, timber

When simply calling `Timber::get_pagination()`, I get this error:

Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(462) : eval()'d code on line 63

Followed by an attempt to echo an array. I'm not actually echoing anything. Full block in `index.php` is

```
if (is_home() || is_archive()) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) {
        $context['pagination'] = Timber::get_pagination(['show_all' => true]);
    }
}
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: If the notice is happening inside the `TwigEnvironment` you need to look inside your template, not the controller

Comment: @DarkBee So would it be something in the Timber classes? I'm not currently using a `.twig` to render anything, and commenting out that line removes the notice.

Comment: @DarkBee Figured it out, didn't realize that the error was from a long string being evaluated, duh! Thanks for the help.